# Firestore basic security rules not working

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Please be humble as I'm very new to iOS swift programming and Firestore.

I have these two structs in Swift:

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Foundation


struct WashingMachine: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var brand = "unknown"
    var price = 0
    var boughtDate: Date
        
  }
```

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Foundation

struct PrivateData: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var roles: Dictionary<String, String>
}
```

I have tried to follow Firestore's guidelines in creating server security so only the logged in user with the role of 'Owner', given in the PrivateData subcollection can access a washingMachine document.

My rules in Firestore look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /washingMachine/{docID} {
    
        allow read: if isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/$(docID)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == "Owner";
    
        function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }
    
      allow create: if isSignedIn();
        match /privateData/{docID} {
            allow create: if isSignedIn();
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

I have no problem in creating the collection washingMachine and a subcollection privateData to that.
If I take away `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/$(docID)).data.roles[req` in my security rules, I can read the washingMachine documents.
I have however not been able to read the washingMachine document when I add the additional check that the user is represented in the subcollection privateData --> roles.

Anyone who can guide me?

---

**Updated information after trying the proposed security update by @trndjc**

When using these proposed security rules, I can no longer create the privateData subcollection:

```
rules_version = '2';
```

service cloud.firestore {

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }

    match /washingMachine/{docID} {
        allow read: if isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/$(docID)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == "Owner";
        allow create: if isSignedIn();
    }

    match /privateData/{docID} {
        allow create: if isSignedIn();
    }
}
```

}

My function in SwiftUI code looks like this (sorry for the hardcoding):

```
func addDefaultWashingMachine(userId: String) {
    let privateData = PrivateData(
        roles: [userId: "Owner"])
    let washingMachine = WashingMachine(boughtDate: Date.now)
    let collectionRef = db.collection("washingMachine")

    do {
        let newDocReference = try collectionRef.addDocument(from: washingMachine)
        print(newDocReference.debugDescription)

        let subCollectionRef = db.collection("washingMachine").document(newDocReference.documentID).collection("privateData")

        let subDocReference = try subCollectionRef.addDocument(from: privateData)
        
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The result is that only the washingMachine collection is created, but the subcollection privateData isn't. The following error message is given in the printouts.

<FIRDocumentReference: 0x28222c630>
2023-06-18 19:45:47.107265+0200 MyTestApp[7196:3316489] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (107e47088) Stream error: 'Permission denied: Missing or insufficient permissions.'
2023-06-18 19:45:47.108332+0200 MyTestApp[7196:3316489] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Write at washingMachine/E8uAMthVmZ2ZSvji37iX/privateData/ZULclTBPGovQpijy0PW6 failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.

---

Modified the proposed security rules like this to being able to add subcollection privateData:

```
rules_version = '2';
```

service cloud.firestore {

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }

    match /washingMachine/{docID} {
        allow read: if isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/$(docID)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == "Owner";
        allow create: if isSignedIn();
        
        match /privateData/{docID} {
        allow create: if isSignedIn();
        }
        
    }       
}
```

}

I still get the following error when trying to read the document:

*2023-06-18 20:26:46.331840+0200 MyTestApp[7211:3330007] 10.9.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at washingMachine failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
Error getting documents: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}*

I call it by using these functions:

```
func findAllWashingMachinesInCollection() {
    
    db.collection("washingMachine").whereField("brand", isEqualTo: "unknown").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                self.fetchWashingMachine(documentId: document.documentID)
                
            }
        }
    }
}


func fetchWashingMachine(documentId: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection("washingMachine").document(documentId)
    
    docRef.getDocument(as: WashingMachine.self) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let washingMachine):
            self.washingMachine = washingMachine
            print("WASHING: \(washingMachine.brand)")
            self.errorMessage = nil
        case .failure(let error):
            self.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
    }
}
```

The work well if I remove *get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/$(docID)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == "Owner"* in the security rules.

Comment: The Codable classes are likely irrelevant to the problem. Can you edit your question to instead show the minimal code that tries to read from the database and fails, and the error message you get from that?

Comment: I added some additional information. Any obvious rookie mistakes I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're trying to do isn't possible with Firebase security rules. Security [rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), but instead "only" ensure that your code only accesses data that it is permitted to.

So when we look at the check in your rule:

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/$(docID)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == "Owner";
```

This requires that:

- Either the rules engine check each document's private data and only return the documents for which the user is the owner, which violates the **rules are not filters** limitation that I mentioned above.
- Or your code will have to include the same condition, so only requesting the documents for which it is the owner. But that isn't possible, as a query can only filter based on the data in the documents that it returns.

The workaround is to duplicate the data that you want to filter on (so the `roles`) in the parent document, and refer to that both in your security rules and in the query.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the scenario described in [Get to know Cloud Firestore #6](https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw?t=1000) at around 16:40
Based on what the statement that **rules are not filters**, I tried to change the rule to be like this: [get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/private).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == "Owner";] but it didn't help. So I will try out your workaround instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have the roles properly assigned, if the collection and document paths are correct, or if the data in the database reflects these rules, but I do know that your security rules aren't properly written. You must declare the functions outside of the match rules. I've spaced them out here to better illustrate how the rules should look.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        match /washingMachine/{docID} {
            allow read: if isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/washingMachine/$(docID)/privateData/$(docID)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] == "Owner";
            allow create: if isSignedIn();
        }

        match /privateData/{docID} {
            allow create: if isSignedIn();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trndjc for your proposal. I tried it as you wrote, but it gave me the challenge that I can't create the subcollection privateData anylonger. Please see the updated information in my question.

Comment: I just moved "match /privateData/..." to be under the "match /washingMachine/... curly brackets, then the issue was solved.

Comment: @MaxMikkelsen I didn't realize that `privateData` was a subcollection of `washingMachine`; I assumed it was its own top-level collection. Well, there you go!

Comment: no worries, thanks for improving the structure anyway :) 
My main challenge is to get the reading to work together with the privateData. Any ideas in that area?

Comment: @MaxMikkelsen can you be more specific about the main challenge? I don't follow.

Comment: I'm trying to only have access to a document in `washingMachine` if the subcollection `privateData` 's ´roles' contain the logged in user's `uid` and is `owner`

Comment: @MaxMikkelsen I'm sorry but I still don't fully understand. You said if the subcollection's role contains the logged-in user's identifier. A subcollection doesn't have roles, auth users do. And subcollections don't contain uids, subcollections contain documents and documents contain fields which can include uids. Be very precise with your wording as to what exactly you want and hopefully we can help.

Comment: I'll give my best shot. 
As seen in my code example, I have a struct reflecting a privateData document, with one field named `roles`. This field is a dictionary [String:String] where the first String is set as a string representation of a user's UID. The second String is just 'Owner'.  Example: ["K0HNsK0uMzOj821hOrsBwimTSaC2":"Owner"]

I can as mentioned add documents to the collection `washingMachine`and its subcollection `privateDate`.  To make that happen, I use the function named `addDefaultWashingMachine(userId: String)` given in my code example.

Comment: I can however not get my function `findAllWashingMachinesInCollection()`to return only `washingMachine` documents where the logged in user is _owner_. 

That code is also provided. 
Please let me know if that helps?

Comment: @MaxMikkelsen are you trying to mimic the roles-based access from this link? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

Comment: I am trying to replicate this scenario [Get to know Cloud Firestore #6](https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw?t=1000) described around 16:40 and forward.